# tftp startup problem: recvfrom: Socket operation on non-socket

Tags: tftpd

I am trying to start `tftpd` (on arch without `inetd`) for a simple (or so I thought) operation (nothing permanent).

However, starting `tftpd <directory>` as advised in the manual fails with this comment in syslog:

```
tftpd[PID]: recvfrom: Socket operation on non-socket
```

`strace tftpd` says:

```
(...)
geteuid()                               = 0
setgid(65534)                           = 0
setuid(65534)                           = 0
ioctl(0, FIONBIO, [1])                  = 0
recvfrom(0, 0x603600, 516, 0, 0x6035d0, 0x603828) = -1 ENOTSOCK (Socket operation on non-socket)
brk(0)                                  = 0xbe9000
brk(0xc0a000)                           = 0xc0a000
(...)
```

So, what is going on?  No-one is using UDP port 69 yet, and I have temporarily disabled the firewall.

Comment: `tftpd` run not-under-inet may need a `-l` or `--listen` option, I don't see that in your start command?

Comment: @thrig Thanks very much.  I have the `iputils` variant: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tftpd.8.html which apparently does not accept that parameter. (I tried it anyway and it also `exit`s `1`.)

Comment: Um, from that manual, "The tftpd server should be executed by inetd with dropped root privileges" so it sounds like you need `inetd`, or a flavour of `tftpd` with the `-l` flag otherwise.

Comment: @thrig Yes, that was the solution, thanks.  the `tftpd` that comes with `iputils` just won't run standalone.  I tried a different brand and it worked fine. Thanks.  (If you make this a solution thrig then I will mark it as such.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tftpd` comes in a variety of implementations; some may only be run under an `inetd` daemon, while others support standalone operation. The Linux `iputils` `tftpd` at time of writing only supports operation under an `inetd` daemon, so must be run that way. Other implementations may have a `-l` or `--listen` option to operate as a standalone daemon.